# IntelliJ how to turn of automatic { } when writing JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea, jsx

I'm working with React in IntelliJ and have a annoying issue. When wrting JSX (e.g. in Render) IntelliJ automatically inserts two {} when i press enter/autocomplete a property.

For example when writing the following JS code:

```
const SomeCompenent = () => {
    return (
        <div className="someClassName">
    )
};
```

IntelliJ automatically write `className={}`

It kind of assumes I'm always going to use props which require the {} syntax. However, it reduce the readability of the code (imo) with all the unnecessary {}.

I have tried some different settings in file -> settings -> editor -> general -> smart keys, but to no avail.

Hope someone is able to help.

Comment: I'm not sure about IntelliJ but I'll mention how it is in Webstorm, since it may be the same. If you go to Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> HTML, there's a config option at the bottom that says 'Add for JSX attributes.' You can set it to Quotes, Braces, Based on Type (it will use what's set in PropTypes) or None.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatly there is no such option under HTML/XML in IntelliJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ still doesn't expose JSX attribute style in the UI, but turns out that you can manually edit the config file. This worked for me in IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.3:

1. Switch code style scheme to *Stored in Project*.
2. Open the config file at `/.idea/codeStyles/FoobarSchemeName.xml`.
3. Add `<option name="JSX_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE" value="Based on type" />` entry under `JSCodeStyleSettings` to default to `"` instead of `{` for string props, or `value="None"` to append neither `"` nor `{`.
4. Restart IntelliJ. Just reopening the project wasn't enough for me.

If you're missing `JSCodeStyleSettings`, add it in as follows:

```xml
<component name="ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration">
  <code_scheme name="Project" version="173">
    <JSCodeStyleSettings version="0">
      <option name="JSX_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE" value="Based on type" />
    </JSCodeStyleSettings>
  </code_scheme>
</component>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to preferences
2. Editor -> Code style -> HTML
3. find "Add for JSX attributes"
4. change the value to "Based on type"